# Add user image to agm-marker in Angular 5

Tags: angular, google-maps, icons, google-maps-markers

i'm using **agm-marker** for markers in angular 5. I want to add user images in marker pins like this.

[image]

In **agm-marker** [**iconUrl**] gives limited functionality. Any other suggestions will be appriciated.

here's **template**

```
<div style="height: 440px" id="result_banner">
  <agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]='7'>
    <agm-marker *ngFor="let data of searchResultData" [latitude]="+data.lat" [longitude]="+data.lng" [iconUrl]="marker">
    </agm-marker>
  </agm-map>
</div>
```

Comment: Try this `[iconUrl]='{"url": marker,"scaledSize": {"height": 10, "width": 10}}'`

Comment: @hrdkisback your suggestion works! Thanks 

Answer (score 3):

You have to include agm-overlays in project then you can draw overly and it also provide support to add custom div on map.

```
<agm-overlay
      *ngFor="let driver of driversList"
      [latitude]="driver.latitude"
      [longitude]="driver.longitude"
    >
      <div>
        <img
          style="cursor: pointer;"
          [ngClass]="{
            online: driver.status === 'online',
            offline: driver.status === 'offline'
          }"
          src="{{
           driver.profileImageURL
          }}"
        />

      </div>
    </agm-overlay>
```

Add this in css file

.online {
  border: 3px solid black
}

[image]

Comment: You can use this or the icon as a url with the icon png. In this case you need to have this icons created. Don't know if you already have. If not using overlays is easy because you can do it using only css to create this element with a background image and profile picture over it.
Other thing to concern is which one has better performance if you have a lot of icons. Maybe not your problem. Also, if you have a lot, can use the @agm/js-marker-clusterer together.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the existing api and set the **[`iconUrl`](https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/directives/AgmMarker.html)**

```
<agm-marker
   [latitude]="location.latitude"
   [longitude]="location.longitude"
   [iconAnchorX]="10"
   [iconAnchorY]="10"
   [iconHeight]="20"
   [iconWidth]="20">
   [iconUrl]="user.icon">
 </agm-marker>
```

Comment: `<div style="height: 440px" id="result_banner">
  <agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]='7'>
    <agm-marker *ngFor="let data of searchResultData" [latitude]="+data.lat" [longitude]="+data.lng" [iconUrl]="{ url: 'marker', scaledSize: [10,10], origin: [0,0], anchoriconAnchor: [7,7] }">
    </agm-marker>
  </agm-map>
</div>`

Comment: url just takes the image url dont pass other parameters

Comment: then i change the code a little to `[iconUrl]="{ url: 'marker', scaledSize: [10,10], origin: [0,0], iconAnchor: [7,7] }"`. then it give error of **scalesize** is not a size and **height** is not a number.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172944/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-zeeshan-malik).

Comment: Try this `[iconUrl]='{"url": marker,"scaledSize": {"height": 10, "width": 10}}'`